# JSON error while validation it for use in flutter

Tags: json, database, flutter, validation

I am new to JSON files
my json file is giving this

> Error: Parse error on line 34:
> ...tion.do?stCd=WB",        },      "applyOnline":
> ----------------------^
> Expecting 'STRING', got '}'

error when vadidating on https://jsonlint.com/
My JSON file =>
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RahulBagdiOfficial/rto_app_flutter/master/assets/json/data.json
I am not good in asking questions, if you need more details comment below ):
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

sorry but I (android studio automatic formatter)solved it. IDK how but it worked!!!